Recover a corrupted pickle file
I have a corrupted pickle file. I follow this to try to recover my file: how to read corrupted pickle file
I read and try to understand how the file work to complete the file and as a result, I complete that content file that generate by command 'python -m pickletools ./index.pkl >> recover.txt'. But now i dont know how to turn the recover.txt file into .pkl file again. FOr the hexfile, i change to get the file end with .ubusb by compare to a working OK hexfile, But the problem is i dont know how to complete the end of file. Anyone working on this problem ? Please help me because the file corrupted is so important!.
The end of the hexfile of the corrupted .pkl

The end of the hexfile of the working OK .pkl


So what happens when you attempt to read the file? What's the error message you're getting?

(And as far as I know, there's no way to turn the output of pickletools back to a pickle.)

@AKX when i use open("index.pkl") it show error that Ran out of input. I 've check by using pickletools and see that my file end like this:
2652162: h            BINGET     28
2652164: }            EMPTY_DICT
2652165: \x94         MEMOIZE    (as 17389)
2652166: u            SETITEMS   (MARK at 2650739)
2652167: b        BUILD
2652168: \x8c     SHORT_BINUNICODE 'ce1a5a4b-8a7e-4e76-9022-46be613cca6b'
2652206: \x94     MEMOIZE    (as 17390)


The working fine file will end like this:
2682677: j        LONG_BINGET 20956
2682682: M        BININT2    2262
2682685: j        LONG_BINGET 20965
2682690: M        BININT2    2263
2682693: j        LONG_BINGET 20976
2682698: M        BININT2    2264
2682701: j        LONG_BINGET 20985
2682706: M        BININT2    2265
2682709: j        LONG_BINGET 20994
2682714: u        SETITEMS   (MARK at 2680585)
2682715: \x86 TUPLE2
2682716: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 21004)
2682717: .    STOP
highest protocol among opcodes = 4

I read the link that i provide in my post and i've check that if i can fix the hexfile generated by xxd. I can recover the .pkl

Right, "ran out of input" sounds like the file has been truncated – pickle is trying to read more stuff out of it, but there isn't any... You would need to figure out what the opcode is it's trying to read, and maybe just get rid of it. But you wouldn't get all of the data back, just whatever's left.
